# AngularJS - Filtering Json by a variable

Tags: json, angularjs, filter

I am working on a single page app using dynamic routing. I get my bookid from the URL as below

```
myApp.controller('BookCtrl', function($scope,$routeParams) {
    $scope.mybookid=$routeParams.bookurl;
});
```

Here is my data

```
var bookdata  = {
"records": [
  {
    "seriesid": "SpectrumSeries",
    "name": "White Curse",
    "bookid": "WhiteCurse",
    "image": "book1",
  }

...
]};
```

In the above controller, how to I filter out an object that has bookid that equals to $scope.mybookid? I know I can do this by ng-repeat and filter but is there a more efficient way?

Comment: is `bookid` unique in `records`?

Comment: so instead array you can use object and just get value by property name, like: `var bookdata  = {
"records": {
  "WhiteCurse" : {
    "seriesid": "SpectrumSeries",
    "name": "White Curse",
    "bookid": "WhiteCurse",
    "image": "book1",
  }` and then `records[$scope.mybookid]`

Comment: mybookid is a string, (.i.e. "WhiteCurse", not a number) because I get it from the URL, so is this approach possible?

Comment: you need change your array `records` to object, and then all work, in my sample - records is object, not an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use filter in javascript:

```
var filteredBooks = bookdata.records.filter(function(book){
    return book.bookid == $scope.mybookid; 
});
```

The `filteredBooks` array will contains all the book with your bookId.

Comment: getting property from object, i think more efficient then filtering array